# A variance-mixture model

Tags: real-analysis, probability, functional-analysis, integration, probability-distributions

So I've tried to make a probability distribution which has a tunable degree of kurtosis and which becomes Gaussian if the control-parameter goes to 0. Now Levy-distributions are out of the question, so I had to resort to broadening the [normal distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution).

I've done this by using a [lognormal distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution) for the standarddeviation $\sigma$, I was looking for a simple distribution which only governed positive values. So now I have a probability distribution defined as:

$P(x;\mu,\sigma,\lambda) = \frac{1}{2\pi\lambda}\int\limits_0^\infty\frac{1}{\tau^2}e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\tau^2}-\frac{\log(\sigma/\tau)^2}{2\lambda^2}}d\tau$,

where $\mu$ is the mean of the distribution, $\sigma$ is the most probable standarddeviation in the lognormal distribution and $\lambda$ is a parameter associated with the standarddeviation of the lognormal distribution.

Now I've been working for a while now with this distribution, trying to find some way of calculating this integral (Laplace transform for example), but I didn't succeed. I was hoping wether someone could help me with this one? Some of the calculations I've been able to do with using the integral definition (like for example the properties of the distribution: skewness and kurtosis), but upon practical applications it goes wrong. Simply plotting this equation (upon numerical integration) costs my computer half a minute (I'm using Mathematica 8).

So all help is appreciated!

Comment: You are attempting to build a [variance-mixture model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_variance-mean_mixture). If one uses $\Gamma$-distribution instead of log-normal, the integral becomes doable. The mixture is known as [variance-gamma distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance-gamma_distribution).

Comment: @Sasha Do you perhaps know any literature about the subject ? Anyway thanks for the comment I will look into this! Other suggestions are always welcome, if it were possible to solve this one that'd be great!

Comment: @Sasha, if you'd put that in an answer, then I could accept it as an answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pasting my earlier comment as an answer.

> You are attempting to build a [variance-mixture model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_variance-mean_mixture). If one uses $\Gamma$-distribution instead of the log-normal, the integral becomes doable. The mixture is known as [variance-gamma distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance-gamma_distribution).

Incidentally, the variance-gamma distribution is supported in v9 of *Mathematica* as `VarianceGammaDistribution` (see the [ref-page](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/VarianceGammaDistribution.html))).

Comment: again thanks for the quick response! Looking at one of my earlier comments, the question got back to me: "Do you perhaps know about some literature about the subject of variance-mixture models" ?

Comment: Perhaps [arXiv:1106.2333](http://arxiv.org/abs/1106.2333) could be a good start. Also check out [the original article](www.jstor.org/stable/1402598) of O. Barndorff-Nielsen for further historical references.